# Free Subscription is the only In-App purchase type

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to integrate In-App purhcase in my iPhone app. When I click on "Manage In-app Purchases" I see only

"Free Subscription". I dont see "Consumable" or any other types. Apple says I need to finish some contracts to see missing types. What kind of contracts should one fill and agree to support "Consumables" in one's iOS app

[image]

Answer (score 26):

You have to agree on the apple contracts for paid application.

Go to "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" section on https://itunesconnect.apple.com and Request for the Paid application contract. Fill up the contact info + bank info + tax info and once the status changes to processed, you will be able to test the InApp purchase for the products.

Only the free subscriptions you can test without setting up those info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the agreements section and agree with the contracts first then the option will appear. I believe is contracts and agreements in iTunes connect. After that you can allow consumable option.

Answer (score 0):

For adding consumable or non consumable in app purchases, one must be a team agent or other iTunes Connect user with an Admin or Finance role.

Then only Agreements, Tax, and Banking section will be visible. If this section isn’t visible, the iTunes Connect user account doesn’t have a role with access to contract information. That user should contact a user with an Admin role to change the roles assigned to the account.

Reference: [Apple Document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html)