# adding in app purchases on iTunesConnect just allow the Free Subscription

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

in App Purchase only allows my to create `Free Subscription` in App, Can any body help me to resolve it.

I know you can say this question is duplicated, but I didn't find any help from those links.

so please take this question serious and answer it. Thanks.

[Free Subscription is the only In-App purchase type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619332/free-subscription-is-the-only-in-app-purchase-type)
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've to agree the terms and conditions for paid app from iTune Connect.
Go to iTuneConnect home screen and select **Contact, Tax & Banking** there you have to send request for **iOS Paid Apps**. Accept the terms, and done. now you'll be able to see all types on In-App Purchases.

Comment: bt i can not see any button to send request!! Why?

Comment: What if someone is showing the iAds and giving option for IAP also?

Comment: Does Apple charge anything if I request for Paid Application?